# How to add radio button selection to a list in c#?

Tags: c#, list, radio-button

I am relatively new to C# and I am trying to create an app where a user can supply a lot of data about bonds. So I have a lot of textboxes for bonds names etc and I have 2 radio buttons inside a groupbox to define a coupon type. So, I have a radio button for Fixed and for Zero. What I want to happen is that when a user selects one of the radio buttons, that the selection will be added to a list.

I was trying to do a boolean and say:

```
if (rdbtn_Fixed.Checked)
{
    string couponType = rdbtn_Fixed.Text;
}
else
{
    if (rdbtn_Zero.Checked)
    {
        string couponType = rdbtn_Zero.Text;
    }
}
```

Though I know it was a long shot because I didn't think you can define a variable that way. I have a method calling a different class as such:

```
Bond bonds = CreateBond(cusip, ticker, name, maturityNoTime, coupon, primaryBook, assignedBook, couponType, positionValue);
```

So I am having trouble defining the couponType as whichever radio button is selected.

Comment: Declare the variable `couponType` outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to put the declaration of `couponType` outside the `if`:

```
string couponType = null;

if (rdbtn_Fixed.Checked)
    couponType = rdbtn_Fixed.Text;
else if (rdbtn_Zero.Checked)
    couponType = rdbtn_Zero.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks!! That worked very well...can't believe I forgot to initialize it! Tuesday morning...all can be forgiven! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 string couponType = rdbtn_Fixed.Checked == true ? rdbtn_Fixed.Text : rdbtn_Zero.Text;
```